# Can I flag a question that should be closed in the first/ late answer queues?

Tags: support, review-queues, late-answers, first-answers

When reviewing first and/or late answers I come across answers to low quality questions that are still open, but should have been closed in the first place.

Is it possible in this case to flag the question for closure and leave (ignore) the answer?

Comment: You could skip the answer, and then flag the question.

Comment: Process the answers and question, as appropriate, you shouldn't just limit your actions to the answer(s) you are reviewing.

Answer (score 7):

You can't perform these actions on *questions* in any of the **Low Quality Answers**, **First Answers**, or **Late Answers** views.

However, you *can* open the question itself in a new browser tab and interact with the question in an unrestricted fashion (for actions your reputation grants you). From here you would be able to vote to close or flag the question if you feel it is appropriate.

To use an example from the **First Answers** queue, the question title acts as a link to the answer in the normal Q&A view. Click this, or open the link in a new tab, then scroll to the top to get to the question where you can perform any actions you normally would be able to.

[image: Example View]