# What is the correct action to take when encountering spam in the Low Quality Answer review queue, once you've flagged it for spam?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam, low-quality-answers

I know the correct course of action on the answer itself is to go to the question post and flag the answer as spam ([since you cannot flag from the LQA view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417950/584676)).

However, what action should we take on the *review* itself? Unlike the other answer queues, **Low Quality Answers** does not have a review action of **Other action**. Per [this answer by @ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417875/584676), no additional action should be taken on spam posts:

> There's no need to do anything else - except perhaps leave a comment if it's subtle spam

But there is still some ambiguity because:

1. The above answer is centered around close-votes, not delete-votes
2. There is no review queue guidance (which the question wasn't centered around)
3. **Looks Good** or **Skip** seem incorrect, since the post would have already been identified as problematic by the reviewer

Comment: Recommend Deletion -> No comment needed?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine The second answer link I posted actually is in response to getting a wrist slap by the mod team for taking any action on spam besides flagging as spam. While it turns out it was a mistake, the guidance of that answer still suggests taking no additional action. Since there is no explicit guidance here, I'd like to avoid such misunderstandings for myself and others with a concrete answer to what the correct review action should be.

Comment: That guidance was specifically about _close voting_ spam. I can't imagine any mods having issues with you recommending spam for deletion.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe deleting as spam has additional consequences than normal deletion does. I recall an answer about that somewhere on meta, but am having trouble locating it.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest yes, -100 rep penalty, IIRC

Comment: It has the -100 rep penalty, plus I think something IP associated. But people close voting and spam flagging was a historical problem (see: [Educating people to flag spam and not vote to close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327636/3270037)), hence why the mods are strong on that guidance.

Comment: Also, the post gets locked + a small aesthetical side-effect (masking) happens. See the [MSE canonical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/786798) on red flags for a more detailed explanation of what happens when a post with red flags is deleted.

Comment: So it *may* be that voting for normal deletion is not desired, either. Hence, the question. Although the real issue here is that the LQA queue doesn't have an **Other action** selection like its other answer review queue bretheren.

Comment: Skip maybe? Say thanks to the underthought systems that plague all review queues...

Answer (score 19):

There's some disparity between what the system expects and what needs to happen for the post to be handled appropriately. The system is expecting "Delete" or "Recommend deletion". I know this because the only way to pass a spam *audit* is to choose to delete the post.

In my opinion, this is absolutely **not** the correct way to handle this type of post. If the post is deleted from review, the system will not apply the 100 reputation penalty.

Worse, pending red-flags are cleared (marked helpful) when the post is deleted regardless of whether the penalty was applied or not.

Unfortunately, I think all supported actions are inappropriate:

- "Looks OK" spam typically does not.
- "Edit" There's no reason to do this. (1) it will kick the post out of LQA queue and (2) a substantive edit might make the spam harder to identify
- "Delete"/"Recommend deletion" If enough users choose this option the post will be deleted without applying the penalty.

I highly recommend flagging the post as spam and then skipping. In this case, I consider "Skip" to mean "not something this queue can handle". Additionally, skip makes no progress towards completing the review, which increases the chances that 6 users will be able to see the post and flag it (as compared to the chances of finding this specific answer in a sea of millions).

Some related posts:

- [When confronted with spam in the LQP queue, should I press 'delete' or 'looks okay'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305799)
- [Would it be possible to add flagging/voting to "Low Quality Answers" review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252768)

As an addendum, both [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) and [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) generally have users willing and able to assist with the reporting/handling of spam.

Comment: I'd still click "Recommend Deletion" for spam audits, else you may get immediately review banned after subsequently failing two (maybe non-obvious) spam audits. This is the mistake I made some time ago - skipped spam audits because I didn't know how to handle them (flagging didn't work obviously), then missed two difficult ones, and boom. It's really strange that there isn't a first class "spam" option for completing the review, given that many (all?) audits are about spam.